# Inno Setup SHA256 function results do not match any other implementation

Tags: cryptography, inno-setup, sha, pascalscript

The built in functions provided by Inno Setup `GetSHA256OfUnicodeString` and `GetSHA256OfString` do not seem to generate the same results as any other implementation I could find.

I need to generate the SHA256 of a String that is provided during installation and check against it later from a piece of Java code.

However, the SHA256 values generated by the Inno Setup functions do not match anything I can create with other implementations or online calculators.

E.g., the Inno Setup manual provides this example:

```
var SHA256: String;
begin
  SHA256 := GetSHA256OfUnicodeString('Test');
  // SHA256 = 'fe520676b1a1d93dabab2319eea03674f3632eaeeb163d1e88244f5eb1de10eb'
end;
```

However, using for example [this online calculator](https://dencode.com/hash), the result for 'Test' is:

```
532eaabd9574880dbf76b9b8cc00832c20a6ec113d682299550d7a6e0f345e25
```

I found the [implementation of the Inno Setup SHA256 functions here](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/main/Projects/InstFunc.pas), however, the buck stops there for me as I cannot find the source for the `THashSHA2` class used there.

Is there some length byte(s) included in the SHA256 or why is the result different? Any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting together what others posted in the comments:

1. The example is wrong, as it shows a hash of `test`, not `Test`.
   I have [submitted a correction](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/pull/406).
2. The Pascal Script `UnicodeString` uses UTF-16LE, not the UTF-8 (ASCII) that your online calculator uses by default.

So this gives you the hash shown in the example:
https://dencode.com/hash/sha256?v=test&oe=UTF-16LE&nl=crlf